# How to access a called function's arguments outside of that function in R?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am wondering if it is possible to access a called function's arguments outside of that function in R?
For example if I had the following function:

```
testfunc = function(a,b,c=1,d=2){
return(list(res1 = a+b,res2 = c+d)) 
}
```

and I called that function like so:

```
testfunc(4,5)
```

I would like a way to access the values of each argument outside of the function without adding anything inside the function such as match.call etc. So, ideally I would like a wrapper function that goes 
getarguments(testfunc(4,5)) and returns:
a=4,b=5,c=1,d=2

Is this possible? Thanks so much.

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do this?

Comment: I want to have an easy way to define a functions arguments globally for the purposes of debugging.

Comment: I'm still not completely understanding what you're trying to do.  But it seems like there might be a better way to accomplish what your actual goal is if you can explain that in a bit more detail.

Comment: Whenever I am debugging a function I have to define each of the arguments globally so that I can go through the code of that function line by line to see what is happening in each step. Some of the functions I am working with have dozens of arguments so it takes a long time to get each argument defined. I would like an easy way to have these defined automatically for me. So if I had a function with arguments "a", "b", ..., through "z" they would all be globally defined for me instead of me having to type them out myself. Hopefully this helps

Comment: Are you aware of the `debug` and/or `browser` functions?

Comment: If you're fine with a named list of all default values for a function's arguments, use `formals`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't recommend doing this, but it is in theory possible. How about

```
getarguments <- function(x) {
  call<-substitute(x)
  fx<-eval.parent(call[[1]])
  body(fx) <- as.call(list(quote(`{`), quote(return(mget(ls())))))
  call[[1]] <- fx
  eval.parent(call)
}
getarguments(testfunc(4,5))
```

which returns

```
list(a = 4, b = 5, c = 1, d = 2)
```

When ever I need to do something like this, I tend to use `debugonce(testfunc)`. Then you can call `testfunc(4,5)` and enter into the browser. You can print any of the variables you want at that point. See the `?browser` help page.

Comment: I like the answer because it does what is asked for in the question. But I think from what they describe in the comments they would be better served by learning about `debug` and `browser`.

Comment: @Dason I added that info as well. I agree it's important.

Comment: Thank you both Dason and MrFlick so much for your help. This is exactly what I wanted to do. I have also looked into debug and browser and they seem very useful as well. Cheers guys.